# Get country name from country code in .net

Tags: .net, country-codes

I know how to get the country name with a country code:

```
new RegionInfo("de").EnglishName
```

But how can i get the country code with a given english-name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as simple as that:

```
var name = "Germany";
var allRegions = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Select(x => new RegionInfo(x.LCID));
var germanyCode = allRegions .FirstOrDefault(region => region.EnglishName == name)?.Name;
```

Note, that when the `germanyCode` is null then somebody messed up the English name.